# Java Spring MVC + Hibernate - sessionFactory "unsatisfied dependency" errror

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, maven, spring-mvc

I'm in the middle of creating my first Spring + Hibernate webapp and this is what I have in console:

```
Root Cause
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'quizDAOImpl': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'sessionFactory'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/dispatcher-servlet.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.AnnotationException: No identifier specified for entity: com.kubacki.entity.Quiz
```

I tried to find already existing solutions but nothing seems to work, would you be able to help me please?

I am not sure if the issue may be caused by bad XML configuration or some mistake in coding itself, from my perspective "sessionFactory" bean is correctly configured in XML and there should be no problem with injecting it.

Additionally, I'am using Maven for this project but I have already listed all spring + hibernate stuff in pom.xml

Here is my source code:

QuizDAO:

```
package com.kubacki.dao;

import java.util.List;

import com.kubacki.entity.Quiz;

public interface QuizDAO {

    public Quiz getQuiz(int id);

    public List<Quiz> getQuizzes();

}
```

QuizDAOImpl:

```
package com.kubacki.dao;

import java.util.List;

import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.query.Query;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

import com.kubacki.entity.Quiz;

@Repository
public class QuizDAOImpl implements QuizDAO {

    @Autowired
    private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    @Override
    public Quiz getQuiz(int id) {

        Session tempSession = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();

        Quiz tempQuiz = tempSession.get(Quiz.class, id);

        return tempQuiz;
    }

    @Override
    public List<Quiz> getQuizzes() {

        Session tempSession = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();

        Query<Quiz> theQuery = tempSession.createQuery("from quiz", Quiz.class);

        List<Quiz> tempQuizzes = theQuery.getResultList();

        return tempQuizzes;
    }

}
```

Web.xml:

```
<!DOCTYPE web-app PUBLIC
 "-//Sun Microsystems, Inc.//DTD Web Application 2.3//EN"
 "http://java.sun.com/dtd/web-app_2_3.dtd" >

<web-app>

  <display-name>WebApp</display-name>

    <servlet>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>

  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

dispatcher-servlet.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd">

    <!-- Add support for component scanning -->
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.kubacki" />

    <!-- Add support for conversion, formatting and validation support -->
    <mvc:annotation-driven/>

    <!-- Define Spring MVC view resolver -->
    <bean
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/view/" />
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
    </bean>

    <!-- Step 1: Define Database DataSource / connection pool -->
    <bean id="myDataSource" class="com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource"
          destroy-method="close">
        <property name="driverClass" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
        <property name="jdbcUrl" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/quizdb?useSSL=false" />
        <property name="user" value="root" />
        <property name="password" value="admin" /> 

        <!-- these are connection pool properties for C3P0 -->
        <property name="minPoolSize" value="5" />
        <property name="maxPoolSize" value="20" />
        <property name="maxIdleTime" value="30000" />
    </bean>  

    <!-- Step 2: Setup Hibernate session factory -->
    <bean id="sessionFactory"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="myDataSource" />
        <property name="packagesToScan" value="com.kubacki.entity" />
        <property name="hibernateProperties">
           <props>
              <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</prop>
              <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
           </props>
        </property>
   </bean>    

    <!-- Step 3: Setup Hibernate transaction manager -->
    <bean id="myTransactionManager"
            class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.HibernateTransactionManager">
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory"/>
    </bean>

    <!-- Step 4: Enable configuration of transactional behavior based on annotations -->
    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="myTransactionManager" />


</beans>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per the error

```
No identifier specified for entity: com.kubacki.entity.Quiz
```

I think, You are missing a field annotated with `@Id` in `Quiz` class. Each @Entity must have an @Id - this will be a primary key in your database.

Comment: @ Amdg  There is no primary key.

Comment: Hibernate requires a primary key. Ref : [here](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.5/reference/en/html/mapping.html#mapping-declaration-id), [hibernate forums](https://forum.hibernate.org/viewtopic.php?f=1&t=938887)